# Не удается обработать нажатия клавиш экранной клавиатуры в Android

Tags: android, api, клавиатура

Доброго времени суток! В своем приложении мне понадобилось реализовать ввод текста с экранной клавиатуры без использования `EditText`. Я хочу, чтобы текст, введенный пользователем, рисовался с помощью `Canvas` на `SurfaceView`.
Сама клавиатура вызывается следующим кодом:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mainActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(mainActivity.getCurrentFocus(),InputMethodManager.RESULT_SHOWN);
```

Фокусом является объект класса, унаследованного от `SurfaceView` и реализующего `OnKeyListener`. Проблема в том, что метод `onKey()` вызывается не во всех случаях, например, если переключить клавиатуру на русский язык, или использовать нестандартную клавиатуру, то `onKey()` вызываться не будет. Однако, все прекрасно работает с раскладкой qwerty (стандартной клавиатуры). Как в таком случае лучше получать информацию о вводимых символах? Где можно почитать про взаимодействие IME и `EditText`? Как последний получает от клавиатуры символы? Заранее спасибо!